# Are there any tools to dynamically generate flat files from SQL objects?

Tags: sql-server, file, ssis, dts

I'm looking for a tool or component that generates flat files given a SQL Server's query result (from a stored procedure or a SELECT * over a table or view). This will be a batch process which runs every day, and every day a new file is created.

I could use SQL Server Integration Services (DTS), but I have a mandatory requirement: the output of the file need to be dynamic. If a new column is added in my query result, the file must have this new column too, without having to modify my SSIS package. If a column is removed, then the flat file no longer will have it. I’ve tried to do this with SSIS, but when I create a new package I need to specify the number of columns. Another requirement is configuring the format of the output, depending on the data type of the column. If it’s a datetime, the format needs to be YYYY-MM-DD. If it’s a float, then I need to use 2 decimal digits, and so on.

Does anyone know a tool that does this job?

Thanks

Comment: You can do it with SSIS using Scripting component, but it will be more difficult than creating custom app in C# or any other language of your choice. Another option - someone may have done this as custom SSIS task, try these guys: http://www.cozyroc.com/

Comment: I've asked CozyRoc and the response was that their component fits my requirements. I’ll try it with a proof of concept, thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a tool that will do this, but it would be pretty simple to implement a custom application that uses a DataReader to get the output and simply dumps it to a flat file.

Comment: In fact, we do have a custom application that generate files, but it isn’t dynamic in that way. We’re about to change it, but our manager asked us to look for and try a ready-to-use tool. Thanks!